# OpenDNS: Block "File Sharing" Category But Allow OneDrive

Tags: dns, onedrive, opendns

I am using OpenDNS to block the entire category "File Sharing" because my son is randomly downloading illegal MP3s and I need to prevent him from doing that. However, this has also broken OneDrive sync on our Windows 10 computers. The OneDrive app in the notification area is stuck at "Signing in", and an error box displays the message, "Sorry, there is a problem with the OneDrive servers. Please try again in a few minutes." What URLs do I need to manually allow in OpenDNS in order to allow OneDrive to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an email received from 1drv@supportcenteronline.com:

```
Here is the initial list of core domains for OneDrive.

Supported IP ports & protocols = :80/HTTP & :443/HTTPS
(Note: OneDrive runs as (SSL) secure service, all :80/HTTP requests will
redirect to :443/HTTPS)

akamaihd.net
spoprod-a.akamaihd.net

1drv.com
*.files.1drv.com

Live.com (recommend opening to *.live.com)
onedrive.live.com​
*.onedrive.live.com 
*.*.onedrive.live.com
storage.live.com 
*.storage.live.com 
*.*.storage.live.com 
*.groups.office.live.com
*.groups.photos.live.com​ 
*.groups.skydrive.live.com
favorites.live.com​
login.live.com
oauth.live.com
photos.live.com
skydrive.live.com​

live.net
api.live.net
apis.live.net
docs.live.net
*.docs.live.net
policies.live.net
*.policies.live.net
settings.live.net
*.settings.live.net
skyapi.live.net
snapi.live.net​

livefilestore.com
*.livefilestore.com
*.*.livefilestore.com

MSN.com
storage.msn.com
*.storage.msn.com
*.*.storage.msn.com

mesh.com
*.mesh.com

onedrive.com
onedrive.com
*.onedrive.com

sfx.ms p.sfx.ms
```

Using this information, I was able to narrow down the list of "never block" items to approximately 8 items. Hope that helps someone else!